# Android: How to check/uncheck a RadioButton inside a RadioGroup programmatically in Java

Tags: java, android, radio-button, radio-group

I have to activities, MainActivity and settingsActivity. Because of that I'm using the methods `onPause` and `onResume` in the settingsActivity. So that the things I have done in the settingsActivity are saved after switching to MainActivity and back again.

**settingsActivity:**

Here I have a `TextView` (called "settings2") as a kind of variable and my three `RadioButtons` (`radio0`, `radio1` and `radio2`) which are inside a `RadioGroup`. 
After switching to the MainActivity my programe puts "0" in a file (which is saved on the sdcard) if `radio0` was last checked. But if `radio1` was last checked, it puts 1 in that file. And if `radio2` was last checked, it puts 2 in that file. 
I used this in the method `onPause`.

Then in the method `onResume` I read the text of that file and put it in the `TextView` "settings2".
After this code (still in `onResume`) I want to check/uncheck my `RadioButtons`. So if the text of the `TextView` "settings2" is "0" the `RadioButton` `"radio0"` shall be checked and the others not. If the text of this `TextView` is "1" the `RadioButton` `"radio1"` shall be checked and the others not. And if the text of this `TextView` is "2" the `RadioButton` `"radio2"` shall be checked and the others not.
To do this I used the following two codes but unfortunately they didn't work.

First code:

```
if (settings2.getText().equals("0")) {

        radio0.setChecked(true);
        radio1.setChecked(false);
        radio2.setChecked(false);

    } else if (settings2.getText().equals("1")) {

        radio0.setChecked(false);
        radio1.setChecked(true);
        radio2.setChecked(false);

    } else if (settings2.getText().equals("2")) {

        radio0.setChecked(false);
        radio1.setChecked(false);
        radio2.setChecked(true);

    }
```

Second code:

```
if (settings2.getText().equals("0")) {

        radioGroup1.check(R.id.radio0);

    } else if (settings2.getText().equals("1")) {

        radioGroup1.check(R.id.radio1);

    } else if (settings2.getText().equals("2")) {

        radioGroup1.check(R.id.radio2);

    }
```

Can someone help with this little problem please? I'm looking forward to your help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Here's the problem.

```
 EditText et = ....
 et.getText() // Does not return a string, it returns an Editable.
```

Try:

```
String str = et.getText().toString;
```

Then using str to do your comparisons.

Edit: See source code below on why u have to use Strings to compare.  The default is to compare by reference, but Strings have overriden equals to compare based on string values.  If you aren't using String u won't get matches.

```
public boolean More ...equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String anotherString = (String)anObject;
        int n = count;
        if (n == anotherString.count) {
            char v1[] = value;
            char v2[] = anotherString.value;
            int i = offset;
            int j = anotherString.offset;
            while (n-- != 0) {
                if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I actually don't use an EditText but a TextView. Is there the same problem when using a TextView? Anyway I tried it out and it didn't work. The settingsActivity crashes, now. Eclipse also told me to use it like this: `String str = settings2.getText().toString();` I also compared it with "==". Maybe that was wrong and I should campared with "equals()"?

Comment: Either way, put it in a String.  Only String has overidden equals to compare string values, every other return type from getText compares references.  Second, compare with equals.  You always compare whether strings match with equals.  If you use "==" you're asking if they occupy the same spot in memory.

Comment: Thanks for this good explanation when to use "==" and "equals()"!

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure the TextView text is either 0, 1, or 2? And for a setting like this, you should look into `SharedPreferences`! It is much easier to use and much faster too.

2nd thing you should do is instead of getting the `settings2.getText().toString ()` you should do

`int input = Integer.parseInt (settings2.getText().toString()`

and then use

```
switch(input) {
    case 0:
        // code when text equals 0
    break;
    case 1:
        // code when text equals 1
    break;
    case 2:
        // code when text equals 2
    break;
}
```

Look into this. . I'm on mobile at the moment

EDIT: Formatted text for better view.

EDIT 2 : SharedPreferences example

```
//get your app's Preference Manager
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context); // If you are coding this in your Activity class, you have to use getDefaultSharedPreferences(this) instead!

public int getPrefs(String key) {
    //get an Integer from the preferences
    return prefs.getInt(key, defaultValue);
    //defaultValue is in case a value for the given key is not found, for example, the user runs the app for the 1st time.
}

public void setPrefs() {
    //You need a SharedPreference editor
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
    //SharedPreference work with a key and its value
    prefsEditor.putInt(key, value);
    //You have to commit the preferences, or they don't get saved!
    //If you want to use a save button, you can make the Editor variable into a Global var (class variable) and in your save button's onClick, just commit!
    prefsEditor.commit();
}
```

Comment: This solution works too.  As long as he puts it in something that evaluates equality based on values rather than (just) references it has a chance to work.  Strings and Integers both do this.

Comment: I tried it before with sharedPreferences but I didn't get it. So, I'm rather new to java on android and I wanted to ask if you could show me an example script with the RadioButtons? This would help me a lot to understand the use of your solution very well! Of course I tried to use it first but I got the following: `The method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (CharSequence)`. What does this mean in this case?

Comment: The error was my mistake `settings2.getText()` returns a `CharSequence` variable, but what we need is a `String`, so we have to turn the `CharSequence` in to a `String`, which we can do by adding a `.toString()` (ex.: `settings2.getText().toString()`)

Comment: If you're not in a hurry, I would like to suggest 2 playlists to watch! That's how I learned. Search for "Android tutorials by TheNewBoston" and also "Android tutorials by slideNerd". (I'm not sure if I'm allowed to post external links so I won't, but you can search for them on google/youtube)

Comment: Until you learn more, you can keep using `str.equals(...)` like in the other answer. If you use my way, you will have to make sure that `settings` contains a number!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and also thanks for the SharedPreference example and the video tutorials! These will certainly help me a lot! So, I will try out your examples and then I'll let you know if they worked well! And I think it would be ok if I just ask you again if I have some more problem/questions about this.

Comment: I'm confused, now! I tried your first example with the switch but it didn't work. So, in my MainActivity you can see a menu bar at the buttom when touching the hardware menu button. In this menu bar you can click on settings to go to the settingsActiviy. But as soon as I click this settings button in the menu bar, my app crashes. Is it wrong then if I put this script in the method `onResume`? Do I have to put it in an other method, perhaps? And to the SharedPreferences example, where do I have to put my code there? So, I understand your example, well but I don't know where to put my code :/